# Undefined symbols for architecture in watchKit

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, arm64

The error that Im running into is `Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:`. Below I have provided more in-depth screenshots. The source of the error according to Xcode is within the watchKit extension within the interfaceController. The Class is referenced from a dynamic library. If I actually CMD+Click the framework that Im importing Im taken to the framework in Swift thats fully ported over to Swift, it is originally written in Objective-C. The second image shows my import statement for the class, and the 3rd image shows how I have setup the import statements within the .h of the framework file. 
[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the right sidebar when those files are selected, under `Target Membership`, is your app (with the little pencil icon) checked as a Target Membership?

That should fix your problem.

Comment: It turns out that the .m files within the frameworks where not being linked against the framework itself, only the .h files where.

Comment: questions have tags not answers

Answer (score 1):

It's look like dynamic library doesn't have arm64 architecture is it. In order to verify please use following command against the static library of your dynamic library.

```
lipo -info <libraryName>.a
```

Please make sure that library is added into extension target.

If your library is not static library, and it is framework like .framework, please follow following step. 
1. Go to framework using cd command

```
cd /Users/<User>/<Path>/<Library_Name>.framework
```

2. Use ls command and list out all the files within framework file. You will see three files named as "Library_Name, Headers and Versions".
3. Use following command to display all architecture that library has.

```
lipo -info <Library_Name>
```

4. You can see list of all architecture that library was build for.

Comment: Could you give me a bit more info on where to input this string?

Comment: lipo -info <path to your library> like

lipo -info /Users/<user>/Desktop/iOS/lib<Sample>.a

Comment: Added additional procedure to determine the framework architecture. Please have a look on the edit response.